# add category name to permalinks on product page /category-name/product-name

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, plugins

I'm trying to reconfigure the permalinks used in WooCommerce such that the following format will be displayed: `homesite/category/product`.
Right now, the permalinks only shows under a category page: `homesite/?product_cat="category-name"`

Under the product page: `homesite/?product="product-name"`

Whatever I tried under the *Permalinks* section of WP didn't work.
By the way the reason I'm trying to alter the permalinks is im trying to create a conditional tag for each product category that will display a different message.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, "whatever I tried under 'Permalinks' didn't work? Select "Shop with Category Base". That adds the product category the single product URL.

[image]

Don't forget to choose something other than "default" under the Common Settings for permalinks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried implementing exactly what you described but I don't see any visual changes in the permalink. When I view a single product page I still get the following permalink - homesite/?product=product-name. How come I can't see the category listed before the product name - homesite/category/?product=product-name

Comment: What are your regular permalinks settings? It sounds to me like you are using default...which is to say you are not using pretty permalinks.

Comment: My permalinks settings are: under general settings - default and under product permalink base 'custom base' - /%product_cat%. None of your suggestions worked for me, I mean there wasn't a difference in the permalinks between what I have now and the screenshot above - resulted in the same permalink.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you must choose something *other* than "Default" for the general settings.. otherwise WordPress doesn't use pretty permalinks at all.